# Open Source bug tracking software, implemented in Java

Tags: open-source, java, issue-tracker

I'm looking for the best open source bug tracking software which has lots of features developed in java

I don't see much in top list - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bug-tracking-system

Found jtrac but the project is not active - https://sourceforge.net/projects/j-trac/#screenshots

itracker is there but not pleasing - http://itracker.sourceforge.net/

Please kindly suggest an open source bug tracking in java which can be used and has the following features

1. Responsive UI
2. Security
3. Inbuilt Editor
4. Google Map or Social Media Integration

Comment: Please explain with more details what are the problems of itracker.

Comment: The user interface is not pleasing. Need a very good open source UI

Comment: Please explain in details what is not pleasing. Not enough keyboard shortcuts? You prefer command line? You prefer bright colors? Searching for a string is cumbersome?

Comment: The appearance, coloring, buttons etc.. Also does the UI is responsive?

Comment: Please edit your question to include these requirements. Thanks! :-)